# numpy.gradient() seems to produce erroneous boundary values (using first differences)

Tags: python, numpy

There seems to be a problem with the function numpy.gradient() (numpy 1.9.0) regarding how it computes the boundary (start and end) values (which I know it does using first differences, while central values are computed using central differences). Consider for instance the following example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 4])
arrgrad = np.gradient(arr)
```

I would here expect `arrgrad` to obtain the values

```
[ 1.   1.5  2. ]
```

i.e.

```
arrgrad[0] = (2-1)/1 = 1
arrgrad[1] = (4-1)/2 = 1.5  
arrgrad[2] = (4-2)/1 = 2
```

but I get the result

```
[ 0.5  1.5  2.5]
```

The behaviour of numpy.gradient() from version 1.8.1 (obtained from https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py) seems to produce the correct result, however.

Is the erroneous behaviour described above the a result of a bug? (I'm using Python 3.4.2, 64 bit.)

Comment: There is no other code, only the three lines shown at the top. Do you both really get the result [1, 1.5, 2] from those three lines, using numpy 1.9.0?

Comment: @andreasdr, I have your same `[0.5,1.5,2.5]` result on OSx, numpy 1.9.0, with the anaconda distro, 64bit.

Comment: @andreasdr, downgrading to `numpy-1.8.1` solved the problem. I now get `gradient([1,2,4])=[1.,1.5,2.]`. This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Exactly my experience, @GiulioGhirardo. I've submitted a bug report at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5184

Comment: I am able to reproduce this bug with numpy 1.9.0 on both OSX and Ubuntu with both python 2.7 and 3.4, but not with numpy 1.8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the way gradients are calculated was changed between 1.8.1 and 1.9.0 by [332d628](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/332d628744a0670234585053dbe32a3e82e0c4db), so that boundary elements are now calculated using a second-order accurate approximation as well, whereas previously they were only first-order accurate.

However, the documentation on the numpy website does not include 1.9.0 docs, only up to 1.8.1, so to see the proper documentation you can use `np.source(np.gradient)` or `print(np.gradient.__doc__)`.

Comment: See also this thread at the numpy-discussion list: [Numpy-discussion: Changed behavior of np.gradient](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-October/071334.html)